# Arrow pointing on two rows of matrix

Tags: matrices, arrows

How to create an arrow which points on two adjacent rows of matrix (as in picture)? [image]

Comment: Do you have any work to show of what you've tried thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! The purpose of this site is to ask question on codes, not to convert screen shots into TeX code. For newcomers sometimes exceptions are made. In this case you could e.g. use Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}] (mat)
 { \times & \times & \times & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
 ~ & \times & \times & \times & ~ & ~ \\
 ~ & ~ & \times & \times & \times & ~  \\
 ~ & ~ & ~ & \times & \times & \times   \\
 ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \times & \times   \\
 ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \times   \\ 
 };
 \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+1)}] in {1,...,5}
 {\draw[<->] ([xshift=-7em+\X*1em]mat.west|-mat-\X-1) -|
 ([xshift=-7.5em+\X*1em]mat.west|-mat-\Y-1) -- ++(0.5em,0);}
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]